# NtFsControlFile seems to fails on files < 728 bytes when compressed

Tags: c, api, winapi, filesystems

I was using the [SDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete) application provided by System Internals to delete files in a secure way but came across an issue where some files where not deleted. I managed to get the SDelete source code and after a bit of digging I found out that the problem only happened with files that where compressed using the filesystem compression option and if they where smaller than 728 bytes. The line of code where it goes wrong is here:

```
    startVcn = 0;
    endOfPrevRun = LLINVALID;
    fileMappings = (PGET_RETRIEVAL_DESCRIPTOR) fileMap;
    while( !(status = NtFsControlFile( FileHandle, NULL, NULL, 0, &ioStatus, FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS, &startVcn, sizeof( startVcn ),fileMappings, FILEMAPSIZE * sizeof(ULONGLONG) ) ) 
        || status == STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW 
        || status == STATUS_PENDING )
```

If this function is called supplying a filehandle of a file compressed and less than 728 bytes the return value is 3221225489: "Reached the end of file".

Presumably this worked on older file systems (I'm on Windows 7) when the application was first written but I assume changes in Windows 7 have made this fail.

For the time being I have worked around the problem by calling the `GetCompressedFileSize` function and if the file is too small, I pad it out with junk until it exceeds 728 bytes. Although this works I would like to know if anyone can suggest a better way of doing this or is there a Windows 7 alternative to `NtFsControlFile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How NTFS Works](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134):

> Clusters Per MFT Record. The size of each record. NTFS creates a file
> record for each file and a folder record for each folder that is
> created on an NTFS volume. **Files and folders smaller than this size
> are contained within the MFT.**

Also:

> NTFS creates a file record for each file and a folder record for each
> folder created on an NTFS volume. The MFT includes a separate file
> record for the MFT itself. These file and folder records are 1 KB each
> and are stored in the MFT. The attributes of the file are written to
> the allocated space in the MFT. Besides file attributes, each file
> record contains information about the position of the file record in
> the MFT. The figure MFT Entry with Resident Record shows the contents
> of an MFT record for a small file or folder. **Small files and folders
> (typically, 900 bytes or smaller) are entirely contained within the
> file’s MFT record.**

I guess that's what you have here - the file data is completely inside the MFT and not present in the "file area" of the disk.

Comment: Yes I read that and was thinking thats what my problem was. Maybe my best option is to figure out how to get the MFT record and delete that.